# Как реализовать качественный эффект свечения графическим примитивам средствами C# GDI+

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, gdi

Есть на 95% законченный проект C# WinForms .Net Core, в нём описаны свои классы графических примитивов(линии, многоугольники, окружности), для отрисовки которых используются стандартные GDI+ средства. Нужно добавить для них АДЕКВАТНЫЙ эффект свечения при отрисовке, как в [этом](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25871514/neon-glow-effect-in-c-wpf) примере в ответах. На WPF это делается одной строчкой кода и выглядит так как нужно, мои потуги добавить что-то подобное для WinForms выглядят как на картинке:

[image: пример]

Метод рисования линии:

```
 public override Image Draw(Image baseImg, double lineWidthPx, double rotationOffset,
        PointF positionOffset, Color penColor = default, double pxPerUnit = 1d, double shinePenMult = 0d, double shineIntensity = 0d)
    {
        using (var gr = Graphics.FromImage(baseImg))
        {
            var br = new SolidBrush(penColor);
            Pen pen = new Pen(br, (float)(lineWidthPx));
            gr.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
            gr.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
            pen.EndCap = LineCap.Round;
            pen.StartCap = LineCap.Round;
            var pStart = new PointF(Start.X + positionOffset.X, Start.Y + positionOffset.Y);
            var pEnd = CalculateEndpoint(pStart, Lenght, rotationOffset + Angle);
            gr.DrawLine(pen, pStart, pEnd);
            //после отрисовки основной линии отрисовывается злосчастная обводка
            DrawBorderShine(lineWidthPx, penColor, shinePenMult, shineIntensity, gr, pStart, pEnd);
        }
        return baseImg;
    }
```

Отрисовка "свечения" заключается в многократной перерисовке поверх существующей линии линий с пониженной прозрачностью:

```
private void DrawBorderShine(double lineWidthPx, Color penColor, double shinePenMult, double shineIntensity, Graphics gr, PointF pStart, PointF pEnd)
    {
        var shinePenMaxWidthPx = shinePenMult * lineWidthPx;
        int drawingStep = (int)Math.Round(shinePenMaxWidthPx / 10d);
        for (int tempPenWidthPx = (int)Math.Round(shinePenMaxWidthPx); tempPenWidthPx > 0; tempPenWidthPx -= drawingStep)
        {
            var alpha = (int)Math.Round((255d * Math.Clamp(shineIntensity, 0d, 1d)));
            Color shineColor = Color.FromArgb(alpha, penColor);
            var brShine = new SolidBrush(shineColor);
            Pen penShine = new Pen(brShine, tempPenWidthPx);
            gr.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
            gr.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
            penShine.EndCap = LineCap.Round;
            penShine.StartCap = LineCap.Round;              
            gr.DrawLine(penShine, pStart, pEnd);
        }
    }
```

По сравнению с примером мои линии совсем не то что нужно. Во-первых горизонтальных линий у меня на рисунке на самом деле 2, одна поверх другой, эффект свечения заметно сильнее чем у линий под углом. Во-вторых, суммирование эффекта с уже отрисованными линиями также имеет место и неприемлемо. Как добиться равномерного эффекта "неона" без наложений в моём случае?

Comment: Как насчет отрисовать то что должно светиться в картинку, картинку разблюрить, и поверх нее теперь отрисовать все еще раз четко?

Comment: В таком случае наложения никуда не денутся, сплошные линии, наверное, будут сильнее выделены, но от суммирования полупрозрачных областей это не спасёт. А конечный результат будет состоять из очень большого количества разных примитивов, и на стыках это будет очень заметно.

Comment: Суммирование полупрозрачных областей вылезает так вы по ходу дела блюрите каждый примитив по отдельности. А это надо делать один раз.

Comment: Логично, а как для рисунка из, например, 1000 примитивов делать весь блюр за один проход? У меня идей нет. В фотошопе этот эффект делается нажатием пары кнопок для всего слоя, но у  меня задача добавить этот эффект программно. Может, есть способы сделать это с использованием другой кисти, не SolidBrush? Или существуют какие-то готовые библиотеки для работы с графикой, о которых я не знаю. Перекопав интернет, мне ничего подходящего не попадалось...

Comment: Да вроде уже написали - все, что должно светится, рисовать в отдельный слой (буфер) потом блюрить (в еще один буфер) потом эти два буфера рисовать на окончательную картинку.

Comment: Это же просто тень. Только цвета не черного.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно реализовать свечение вручную. Например с помощью размытия Гаусса (Gaussian Blur).

Я подбирал эффект на глаз, но смысл везде тот же, только поиграть с настройками.

```cs
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // рисуем картинку
        Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(500, 500);
        Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Red, 5)
        {
            EndCap = LineCap.Round,
            StartCap = LineCap.Round
        };
        using var g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);
        g.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
        g.DrawLine(pen, new Point(50, 450), new Point(250, 50));
        g.DrawLine(pen, new Point(250, 50), new Point(450, 450));
        g.DrawLine(pen, new Point(450, 450), new Point(50, 450));

        // размазываем Гауссом
        double[,] matrix = GetGausianMatrix(25);
        Bitmap bmp2 = ConvolutionFilter(bmp, matrix, 1.1 / matrix.Cast<double>().Sum());

        // рисуем изначальную картинку поверх размазанной
        using var g2 = Graphics.FromImage(bmp2);
        g2.DrawImage(bmp, Point.Empty);

        bmp2.Save("image.png", ImageFormat.Png);
    }

    private static double[,] GetGausianMatrix(int size)
    {
        double[,] matrix = new double[size, size];
        double mid = (size - 1) / 2.0;
        double maxDistance = Math.Sqrt(2 * mid * mid);
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < size; j++)
            {
                double di = Math.Abs(mid - i);
                double dj = Math.Abs(mid - j);
                double distance = Math.Sqrt(di * di + dj * dj);
                double weight = maxDistance - distance;
                matrix[i, j] = 2 * weight * weight;
            }
        return matrix;
    }

    public static Bitmap ConvolutionFilter(Bitmap bmp, double[,] filterMatrix, double factor)
    {
        BitmapData sourceData = bmp.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height), ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
        byte[] pixelBuffer = new byte[sourceData.Stride * sourceData.Height];
        byte[] resultBuffer = new byte[sourceData.Stride * sourceData.Height];
        Marshal.Copy(sourceData.Scan0, pixelBuffer, 0, pixelBuffer.Length);
        bmp.UnlockBits(sourceData);

        int filterSize = filterMatrix.GetLength(0);
        int filterOffset = (filterSize - 1) / 2;

        for (int offsetY = filterOffset; offsetY < bmp.Height - filterOffset; offsetY++)
        {
            for (int offsetX = filterOffset; offsetX < bmp.Width - filterOffset; offsetX++)
            {
                double blue = 0;
                double green = 0;
                double red = 0;

                int byteOffset = offsetY * sourceData.Stride + offsetX * 4;

                for (int filterY = -filterOffset; filterY <= filterOffset; filterY++)
                {
                    for (int filterX = -filterOffset; filterX <= filterOffset; filterX++)
                    {
                        int calcOffset = byteOffset + (filterX * 4) + (filterY * sourceData.Stride);
                        blue += pixelBuffer[calcOffset] * filterMatrix[filterY + filterOffset, filterX + filterOffset];
                        green += pixelBuffer[calcOffset + 1] * filterMatrix[filterY + filterOffset, filterX + filterOffset];
                        red += pixelBuffer[calcOffset + 2] * filterMatrix[filterY + filterOffset, filterX + filterOffset];
                    }
                }

                blue = factor * blue;
                green = factor * green;
                red = factor * red;

                blue = blue > 255 ? 255 : (blue < 0 ? 0 : blue);
                green = green > 255 ? 255 : (green < 0 ? 0 : green);
                red = red > 255 ? 255 : (red < 0 ? 0 : red);

                resultBuffer[byteOffset] = (byte)blue;
                resultBuffer[byteOffset + 1] = (byte)green;
                resultBuffer[byteOffset + 2] = (byte)red;
                resultBuffer[byteOffset + 3] = 255;
            }
        }

        Bitmap resultBmp = new Bitmap(bmp.Width, bmp.Height);
        BitmapData resultData = resultBmp.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, resultBmp.Width, resultBmp.Height), ImageLockMode.WriteOnly, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
        Marshal.Copy(resultBuffer, 0, resultData.Scan0, resultBuffer.Length);
        resultBmp.UnlockBits(resultData);

        return resultBmp;
    }
}
```

Само собой, при таком раскладе рендерить каждую фигуру придется отдельно, но за основу должно сгодиться.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

За основу для решения взята [эта статья](https://softwarebydefault.com/2013/06/09/image-blur-filters/).

---

Поигрался с прозрачностью, вот так получилось.

```cs
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(500, 500);

        Color keyColor = Color.Red;
        Pen pen = new Pen(keyColor, 5)
        {
            EndCap = LineCap.Round,
            StartCap = LineCap.Round
        };
        using var g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);
        g.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
        g.DrawLine(pen, new Point(50, 450), new Point(250, 50));
        g.DrawLine(pen, new Point(250, 50), new Point(450, 450));
        g.DrawLine(pen, new Point(450, 450), new Point(50, 450));

        Bitmap cleanBmp = (Bitmap)bmp.Clone();
        Brush brush = new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(1, keyColor));
        g.FillRectangle(brush, new Rectangle(Point.Empty, bmp.Size));

        double[,] matrix = GetGausianMatrix(25);
        Bitmap bmp2 = ConvolutionFilter(bmp, matrix, 2);

        using var g2 = Graphics.FromImage(bmp2);
        g2.DrawImage(cleanBmp, Point.Empty);

        bmp2.Save("image.png", ImageFormat.Png);
    }

    private static double[,] GetGausianMatrix(int size)
    {
        double[,] matrix = new double[size, size];
        double mid = (size - 1) / 2.0;
        double maxDistance = Math.Sqrt(2 * mid * mid);
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < size; j++)
            {
                double di = Math.Abs(mid - i);
                double dj = Math.Abs(mid - j);
                double distance = Math.Sqrt(di * di + dj * dj);
                double weight = maxDistance - distance;
                matrix[i, j] = 2 * weight * weight;
            }
        return matrix;
    }

    public static Bitmap ConvolutionFilter(Bitmap bmp, double[,] filterMatrix, double intensity)
    {
        double factor = intensity / filterMatrix.Cast<double>().Sum();
        BitmapData sourceData = bmp.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height), ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
        byte[] pixelBuffer = new byte[sourceData.Stride * sourceData.Height];
        byte[] resultBuffer = new byte[sourceData.Stride * sourceData.Height];
        Marshal.Copy(sourceData.Scan0, pixelBuffer, 0, pixelBuffer.Length);
        bmp.UnlockBits(sourceData);

        int filterSize = filterMatrix.GetLength(0);
        int filterOffset = (filterSize - 1) / 2;

        for (int offsetY = filterOffset; offsetY < bmp.Height - filterOffset; offsetY++)
        {
            for (int offsetX = filterOffset; offsetX < bmp.Width - filterOffset; offsetX++)
            {
                double blue = 0;
                double green = 0;
                double red = 0;
                double alpha = 0;

                int byteOffset = offsetY * sourceData.Stride + offsetX * 4;

                for (int filterY = -filterOffset; filterY <= filterOffset; filterY++)
                {
                    for (int filterX = -filterOffset; filterX <= filterOffset; filterX++)
                    {
                        int calcOffset = byteOffset + (filterX * 4) + (filterY * sourceData.Stride);
                        blue += pixelBuffer[calcOffset] * filterMatrix[filterY + filterOffset, filterX + filterOffset];
                        green += pixelBuffer[calcOffset + 1] * filterMatrix[filterY + filterOffset, filterX + filterOffset];
                        red += pixelBuffer[calcOffset + 2] * filterMatrix[filterY + filterOffset, filterX + filterOffset];
                        alpha += pixelBuffer[calcOffset + 3] * filterMatrix[filterY + filterOffset, filterX + filterOffset];
                    }
                }

                blue = factor * blue;
                green = factor * green;
                red = factor * red;
                alpha = factor * alpha;

                blue = blue > 255 ? 255 : (blue < 0 ? 0 : blue);
                green = green > 255 ? 255 : (green < 0 ? 0 : green);
                red = red > 255 ? 255 : (red < 0 ? 0 : red);
                alpha = alpha > 255 ? 255 : (alpha < intensity + 1 ? 0 : alpha);

                resultBuffer[byteOffset] = (byte)blue;
                resultBuffer[byteOffset + 1] = (byte)green;
                resultBuffer[byteOffset + 2] = (byte)red;
                resultBuffer[byteOffset + 3] = (byte)alpha;
            }
        }

        Bitmap resultBmp = new Bitmap(bmp.Width, bmp.Height);
        BitmapData resultData = resultBmp.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, resultBmp.Width, resultBmp.Height), ImageLockMode.WriteOnly, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
        Marshal.Copy(resultBuffer, 0, resultData.Scan0, resultBuffer.Length);
        resultBmp.UnlockBits(resultData);

        return resultBmp;
    }
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Уже когда дописал решение, понял, что правильнее нормалимзовать матрицу сразу при генерации, то есть каждую ее ячейку надо разделить на сумму цифр этой матрицы. То есть правильная матрица для фильтра Гаусса - это та матрица, сумма ячеек которой равна единице. Тогда не придется делить каналы на этот фактор при фильтрации. Но это я оставлю вам для доработки.

Comment: Спасибо, буду пробовать ставить на рельсы своего решения!

Comment: @RunningStone дописал решение с поддержкой альфа-канала. Может грубовато получилось, но работает.