# Image не отрисовывает асинхронно изображение

Tags: c#, wpf, изображения

Сделал обработку изображения в методе Work2, захотел сделать асинхронно чтобы во время работы приложение не подвисало, изображение прекратило отрисовываться.
В данном коде отрисовывается, но приложение подвисает

```
Task task = new Task(() =>
{
    Dispatcher.Invoke(() => {
        var work2Rresult = Work2(screen);
        MyImageWork.Source = work2Rresult;
    });
});
task.Start();
```

А так не подвисает, но и не отрисовывает

```
Task task = new Task(() =>
{
    var work2Rresult = Work2(screen);
    Dispatcher.Invoke(() => { 
        MyImageWork.Source = work2Rresult;
    });
});
task.Start();
```

Как решить проблему чтобы обработка изображения произошла без подвисания приложения на время обработки?
Прилагаю полный код Work2:

```
public BitmapSource Work2(BitmapImage screen)
{
    var bitmap = BitmapImage2Bitmap(screen);
    var tmp = new Bitmap(bitmap.Width, bitmap.Height);
    HashSet<Vector2> vectors = new HashSet<Vector2>();
    var objects = new Dictionary<System.Drawing.Color, PixelObject>();
    

    void f(Vector2 vector)
    {
        vectors.Remove(vector);
        var color11 = bitmap.GetPixel(vector.X, vector.Y);

        var color00 = bitmap.GetPixel(vector.X - 1, vector.Y - 1);
        var color01 = bitmap.GetPixel(vector.X - 1, vector.Y);
        var color02 = bitmap.GetPixel(vector.X - 1, vector.Y + 1);

        var color10 = bitmap.GetPixel(vector.X, vector.Y - 1);
        var color12 = bitmap.GetPixel(vector.X, vector.Y + 1);

        var color20 = bitmap.GetPixel(vector.X + 1, vector.Y - 1);
        var color21 = bitmap.GetPixel(vector.X + 1, vector.Y);
        var color22 = bitmap.GetPixel(vector.X + 1, vector.Y + 1);

        var R = (Math.Abs(color11.R - color00.R) + Math.Abs(color11.R - color01.R) + Math.Abs(color11.R - color02.R) +
            Math.Abs(color11.R - color10.R) + Math.Abs(color11.R - color12.R) +
            Math.Abs(color11.R - color20.R) + Math.Abs(color11.R - color21.R) + Math.Abs(color11.R - color22.R))/8;
        var G= (Math.Abs(color11.G - color00.G) + Math.Abs(color11.G - color01.G) + Math.Abs(color11.G - color02.G) +
            Math.Abs(color11.G - color10.G) + Math.Abs(color11.G - color12.G) +
            Math.Abs(color11.G - color20.G) + Math.Abs(color11.G - color21.G) + Math.Abs(color11.G - color22.G)) / 8;
        var B = (Math.Abs(color11.B - color00.B) + Math.Abs(color11.B - color01.B) + Math.Abs(color11.B - color02.B) +
            Math.Abs(color11.B - color10.B) + Math.Abs(color11.B - color12.B) +
            Math.Abs(color11.B - color20.B) + Math.Abs(color11.B - color21.B) + Math.Abs(color11.B - color22.B)) / 8;


        if (!objects.ContainsKey(color11))
        {
            objects.Add(color11, new PixelObject());
        }
        objects[color11].Add(vector, System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(R, G, B));
    }

    for (short i = 1; i < bitmap.Width - 1; i++)
    {
        for (short j = 1; j < bitmap.Height - 1; j++)
        {
            vectors.Add(new Vector2(i, j));
        }
    }
    while (vectors.Count != 0)
    {
        f(vectors.First());
    }
    Random random = new Random();
    foreach (var obj in objects)
    {
        //var color = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(random.Next(0, 255), random.Next(0, 255), random.Next(0, 255));
        foreach (var pixel in obj.Value.Pixels)
        {
            tmp.SetPixel(pixel.Key.X, pixel.Key.Y, pixel.Value);
        }
    }
    return Bitmap2BitmapImage(tmp);
}
```

И метод откуда вызывается:

```
private void MyForm_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    switch (e.Key)
    {
        case Key.F:
            Hide();
            var screen = Screen();
            Show();
            MyImageOriginal.Source = screen;
            Task task = new Task(() =>
            {
                Dispatcher.Invoke(() => {
                    var work2Rresult = Work2(screen);
                    MyImageWork.Source = work2Rresult;
                });
            });
            task.Start();
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Проблема за пределами показанного кода. Покажиье метод Work2 и текущий метод, откуда оно вызывается целиком.

Comment: @aepot Обновил вопрос, добавил куски кода, но под спойлер не получилось их убрать к сожалению

Comment: Если стопорнуть var work2Rresult = Work2(screen); вне Dispatcher.Invoke то он выдает ошибку внутри объекта:_message "Вызывающий поток не может получить доступ к данному объекту, так как владельцем этого объекта является другой поток."

Comment: Судя по ошибке как я понимаю объект не может из основного потока передастся в другой, хотя с простыми данными как int он работает нормально. Тогда как решить данную задачу?

Comment: Сколько времени работает этот код? Что если его можно ускорить, раз этак в 100? Быть может и не придется тогда мучаться с этими костылями? Что делает этот фильтр? [Вот вам заряд бодрости](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1228842/373567) для приложения, берите, пользуйтесь. И да, объект `BitmapSource` вам нужно создавать строго в UI потоке. Никогда не используйте `GetPixel` и `SetPixel` и ваши 2 секунды превратятся в 40мс. Хотите вообще суперскорости типа обработка FullHD за 4мс - вот [турбоверсия](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1219943/373567), но сразу предупреждаю, это Очень сложно.

Comment: @aepot данный код работает быстро только на изображении 100*100, на 1000*100 я уже не стал дожидаться, не говоря уже о том что мне нужно полный скрин экрана обрабатывать. Сие фильтр берет  пиксель и его соседние пиксели, ищет между ними разницу и выражает в виде цвета по каждому из каналов. Пытаюсь найти способы определения границ объектов на изображении, определить на какой разнице пропадают шумы и остаются реальные границы объектов.

Comment: Изучите подробно первую ссылочку, если код выше вы сами писали, вам будет очень просто разобраться в том, что я там предлагаю. Займитесь оптимизацией с учетом методики работы с битмапом через массив, там пример Оператора Собеля в конце, тоже матричный фильтр. Когда получите нормальную скорость, тогда уже вернитесь к текущему вопросу, если потребуется. Скорее всего не потребуется. Вот еще [ссылка в тему](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1373036/373567). Удалите пока этот вопрос, потом пересоздадите или вернете его назад, но опять же, я уверен, что не придется. Здесь особо отвечать пока нечего.